# Facebook API - Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook application, and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /var/www/customers/vh-394/web/home/dev.a-soft.hu/ssl/api/facebook/xzona/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1106

I'm new with developing Facebook applications and have lost the "App domain", "Site URL", "Canvas URL", "Secure Canvas URL" settings.

Probably there are some URL-settings error, but I don't know exactly how secure URLs work, and how Facebook authentication works.

Can anyone please help me about how to set these URLs above and how I can correct this error?

Thanks

EDIT:

There is a game I'd like to integrate into Facebook, so FB users can play with it, share points, etc. You can find this game here:

https://ssl.a-soft.hu/api/facebook/xzona/_index.php

If you look at this page, you can see me and some of my FB friends, but it's not real, I just learned how FB stores data in arrays so I generated them. In this file there is no connect to FB, or any FB scripts.

The real file is `index.php`, where everything happens. Some months ago I started to create this app using Heroku, but then I bought real ssl domain.

Anyway, the way that my app tries to connect with FB, authenticating it, is the way that Heroku uses.
So it includes "AppInfo.php", "utils.php", "FB sdk" (as Heroku), but I don't know if I failed something to use correctly.

On FB dev page, I didn't fill "App Domains" field, and under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook", I checked only "App on Facebook". In there I filled the fields exactly like this:

Canvas URL: https://ssl.a-soft.hu/api/facebook/xzona/
Secure Canvas URL: (same)
Canvas Page: apps.facebook.com/xzonahu

And now I still have the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /var/www/customers/vh-394/web/home/dev.a-soft.hu/ssl/api/facebook/xzona/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Hope you can help! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which URLs you need depend on exactly what kind of app you're making. Assuming you are making an app that you want embedded in the facebook frame, you should make sure that only the "App on Facebook" box is checked under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"

You need the following URLs:
Hosting URL: This is the url where all of your resources are stored.
Canvas URL: This is the url of the page that should be displayed within the Facebook frame.
Secure Canvas URL: Secure version of the Canvas URL (making both canvas urls the same https url worked for me)
Canvas Page: This is the facebook page people visit to see your app ie. http://apps.facebook.com/myapp

All that said, there are all sorts of things that can go wrong with OAuth so if that doesn't solve the error message come back and we'll see what else it might be.

Comment: Can you paste some of the code from your index.php, specifically the OAuth part?

Comment: Including AppInfo.php:
https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php/blob/master/AppInfo.php

utils.php:
https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php/blob/master/utils.php

"template" index.php:
https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php/blob/master/index.php

You can see everything in these files.

Comment: The index.php you're linking to is different from the page your canvas URL links to. Do you have OAuth code in your landing page? I'd need to glance at the source for https://ssl.a-soft.hu/api/facebook/xzona/ to know. Try looking around for some tutorials on OAuth in php. I'm know there are a few examples on SO and plenty elsewhere on the web.

Comment: I didn't find a place to upload the code itself so I entered it in a textarea here:
https://ssl.a-soft.hu/api/facebook/xzona/_printed_php.php
If it doesn't readable for you because it's not colorful, please help me where I can upload the script.

Comment: For future reference you can put code right into the question and format it so it's clear what it is. It looks like you're trying to use the javascript OAuth code, which I have no experience with. But if you search around here a bit you should be able to find plenty of examples of exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe I have the solution:
The AppInfo.php didn't get the appId, and appSecret from anywhere...
Heroku way did the problem.

Comment: Make sure that the appSecret and appID in your environmental variables matches those given in the facebook developer page for this app. Or you can hard code them in directly to your appinfo.php file.

Comment: At least I had to code them into that file. But now it works! Thanks for help!